# Validate nodejs model using classes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to create a model for NodeJS application using JavaScript and MySQL. Now, I got a tip to use the builder pattern because my object becomes too big and is not readable.
Therefore I created another class and inside the constructor I created an instance of the basic class, like I saw it in the tutorials.

```
// Basic
class User {
    constructor(fname) {
        this.fname      = fname;
    };    
}

// Builder for the user class
module.exports = class UserBuilder {
    constructor(fname) {
        this.user = new User(fname);
    }

    setLname(lname) {
        this.user.lname = lname;
        return this;
    }

    setEmail(email) {
        this.user.email = email;
        return this;
    }

    setPassword(password) {
        this.user.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    setAge(age) {
        this.user.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    setGender(gender) {
        this.user.gender = gender;
        return this;
    }

    setAvatar(avatar) {
        this.user.avatar = avatar;
        return this;
    }

    setPhoneNumber(number) {
        this.user.number = number;
        return this;
    }

    build() {
        return this.user;
    }
}
```

My first question is: how can I validate all the arguments? some of the arguments are not required and the `isAdmin` should be default False.

To check this, I created a basic instance to see how is build.

```
const user = require('./models/user.js');
const User = new user('bob').setAge(22).build();
console.log(User);
```

My second question is how can I create a method inside the class to edit or delete the object and interact with the database. Or it should be in the controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably failed to understand you in some parts of you question. But I tried.
So this basically made the builder class a lot smaller with adding newer properties. Now you just need to provide the key & value to add something to object instead of calling a separate method for it.

*Note* -  **`edit`** and **`remove`** method doesn't need to call **`build`** method to return the base user class.
All of your questions have been answered in the code comments.

```js
/// Basic
class User {
  constructor(fname) {
    this._validate(fname);
    this.fname = fname;
  }

  _validate(param) {
    //what ever you wanna check before adding into object
  }
}

// Builder for the user class
class UserBuilder {
  constructor(fname) {
    this.user = new User(fname);
  }

  addSomething(key, value) {
    if (typeof key !== "string") {
      //throw "Key provided is not a string."
    }
    key = key.toLowerCase();
    if (key == "role") {
      this.user[key] = this.isAdmin();
      return this;
    }

    this.user[key] = value;
    return this;
  }

  isAdmin() {
    // your way to check if its admin.
    /**
     * if(admin == true) {
     *   return true;
     *  } else return false;
     */
  }

  edit(param, val) {
    if (!this.has(param)) {
      //throw
    } else {
      this.user[param] = val;
      //db operation to edit it.
    }
    return this.user;
  }

  /**
   * By delete Object I suppose delete a property.
   */
  remove(param) {
    if (!this.has(param)) {
      //throw
    } else {
      delete this.user[param];
      //db operation to remove it.
    }
    return this.user;
  }

  has(val) {
    return this.user[val] ? true : false;
  }

  build() {
    return this.user;
  }
};

const userr = new UserBuilder("Vox");
console.log(userr.addSomething("age", 19).build());
console.log(userr.edit("age", 21));
console.log(userr.remove("age"));
```

This is what the code logged.

```js
User { fname: 'Vox', age: 19 }
User { fname: 'Vox', age: 21 }
User { fname: 'Vox' }
```